# Resetting page while displaying success message

Tags: controller-extension, pagereference, standardcontroller, refresh, save-and-new

I am trying to reset/refresh my page on my form. I want to refresh the page and then successfully display the success message however, it is only refreshing the page. The success message fails to load. When I take out this code

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/CasePage');
            pr.setRedirect(true);
            return pr;
```

it will successfully display the success message. I dont know how to successfully refresh the page while still displaying the success message. I have tried adding rerender on the form and adding the ID but that does not work.

```
 <apex:pageBlock >
        <div style = "font-size:16px">
            <apex:messages />
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Create a Case" id="test">
            <apex:form id="CaseForm">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <b><td>Type:</td></b>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:100px" value="{! Case.Type }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Status:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{! Case.Status }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Origin:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{! Case.Origin }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Reason:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{! Case.Reason }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:300px" value="{! Case.SuppliedEmail }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:300px" value="{! Case.SuppliedPhone }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subject:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:300px" value="{! Case.Subject }"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description:</td>
                    <td><apex:inputField style="width:550px; height:100px" value="{! Case.Description }"/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <apex:commandButton action="{! save }" value="Save" />
            </apex:form>
            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </div>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Here is my controller code

```
public class CaseController {
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdCntrlr {get; set;}
    
    public CaseController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        
        stdCntrlr = controller;
    }
    
    public Case cs{get; set;}
    public CaseController(){
        cs = new Case();
    }
    
    public PageReference save(){
       if(cs != null) {
            upsert cs;
        } else {
            stdCntrlr.save();
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Successfully inserted Case.'));
            PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/CasePage');
            pr.setRedirect(true);
            return pr;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a custom block with the message that would be rendered after a case insert? Then you could have a "Reload" button there to reload the page and start over.

Here is an example:

VisualForce page:

```
<apex:page id="CasePage" controller="CaseController">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <div style = "font-size:16px">
            <apex:messages />
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Create a Case" id="test" rendered="{!not(showSuccessMessage)}">
                <apex:form id="CaseForm">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <b><td>Type:</td></b>
                            <td><apex:inputField style="width:100px" value="{! cs.Type }"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Status:</td>
                            <td><apex:inputField value="{! cs.Status }"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Origin:</td>
                            <td><apex:inputField value="{! cs.Origin }"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Reason:</td>
                            <td><apex:inputField value="{! cs.Reason }"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email:</td>
                            <td><apex:inputField style="width:300px" value="{! cs.SuppliedEmail }"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Phone:</td>
                            <td><apex:inputField style="width:300px" value="{! cs.SuppliedPhone }"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Subject:</td>
                            <td><apex:inputField style="width:300px" value="{! cs.Subject }"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Description:</td>
                            <td><apex:inputField style="width:550px; height:100px" value="{! cs.Description }"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{! save }" value="Save" />
                </apex:form>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Status" id="caseStatus" rendered="{!showSuccessMessage}">
                <apex:form id="CaseFormStatus">
                    Successfully inserted Case a new case.
                    <apex:commandButton action="{! reload }" value="Reload" />
                </apex:form>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class CaseController {
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdCntrlr {get; set;}

    public CaseController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        stdCntrlr = controller;
    }
    public Boolean showSuccessMessage {get; set;}
    public Case cs{get; set;}
    public CaseController(){
        cs = new Case();
        // hide the block section by default
        showSuccessMessage = false;
    }

    public void save(){
        if(cs != null) {
            upsert cs;
            // show(render) the block section with the message
            showSuccessMessage = true;
        }
        // the code below is not needed
//        } else {
//            stdCntrlr.save();
//            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Successfully inserted Case.'));
//            PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/CasePage');
//            pr.setRedirect(true);
//            return pr;
//        }
//        return null;
    }

    public PageReference reload(){
        // reset the case record after insert
        cs = new Case();
        // hide the message and the block section with the message
        showSuccessMessage = false;
        // refresh the page (redirect to the current page)
        PageReference pr = ApexPages.currentPage();
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ive tried the code above. The message does not appear and the form is not cleared. I appreciate the answer though. Thank you!

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Did you copy the entire page with the controller?